# Undefined array key when sending ID name to php variable (AJAX)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

I have an error

```
Warning: Undefined array key "data" in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\recipe-container.php on line 9 ($product = $_POST["data"];)
Warning: Undefined variable $response in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\recipe-container.php on line 24 (echo $response;)
```

I'm trying to send clicked div's ID (divs that have a "product" class) via AJAX. Div ID name seems to show up in the network tab, but it's undefined in PHP code.

```
//AJAX (head HTML tag)
$(function () { 
        $('.product').on('click', function (e) {
            var product = $(this).attr('id');
            
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: 'php/recipe-container.php',
                data: product,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $(".display_recipe").html(response);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

```
//HTML
<div class="product" id="pizza">pizza</div>
<div class="product" id="lasagna">lasagna</div>
<div class="product" id="sushi">sushi</div>
<div class="display_recipe">
  <?php
    require "php/recipe-container.php";
  ?>
</div>
```

```
//PHP (recipe-container.php)
<?php

function display(){
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cookbook");
    echo "test";
    $product = $_POST["data"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE name = '$product'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $date = $row['date'];

    $response = $name.'<br>';
    $response .= $description.'<br>';
    $response .= $date.'<br>';
    
}
echo $response;

mysqli_close($con);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){ 
    display(); 
}

?>
```

I tried using `isset` and `!empty` for `$_POST["data"];`, but it didn't work. Right now it displays "test", but nothing else. How can I fix it?

Comment: Right now You are sending raw stream. If you want to access it, try this code: `$product = file_get_contents("php://input");`. Find out more about stream wrappers here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: @Robert Unfortunately, it does not work :/

Answer (score 2):

You have to send data as an object not as a variable:
Inside tha ajax request :

```
 data:{
   data: product
 },
 processData:false,
```

Comment: Nothing has changed, there is still an error. This is the network tab payload: [object Object]

Answer (score -1):

This is probably what you wanted to do:

```
data: JSON.stringify{
  data: product
})
```

Comment: Still the same error. This is in my network tab now: {data: "pizza"}
data: "pizza".